# RxJs Streams - Multiple Stream producing single master stream

Tags: typescript, angular5, rxjs5

I have a master list of array of objects and then two other list of selections represented also by arrays. I have these as 3 streams$.

```
master$
filter1$
filter2$
```

On the UI, 
master$ is is bound to a datatable using the async pipe in angular.
filter1$ and filter2$ are bound to UI dropdowns as filter choices.

At any point the filter1$ and filter$ can change depending on what the user selects. I feel there has to be a way to combine the 3 streams together and apply both the filters if required. How can I do this in RxJs ? Can you show me an example. Can I achieve a simple, readable code using combineLatest, pipe and map ?

**Update:**

Below is my current solution, pretty sure there is a better way to compose this:

```
combineLatest(
  master$.shareReplay(1),
  filter1$.shareReplay(1),
  filter2$.shareReplay(1)
)
  .map(([master, filter1, filter2]) => {
    let filtered = master;
    if (filter1.length > 0) {
      filtered = [];
      filtered = master.filter(each => filter2.indexOf(each.organizationId) !== -1);
    }
    if (filter1.length > 0) {
      master = filtered;
      filtered = [];
      filtered = master.filter(each => filter2.indexOf(each.organizationId) !== -1);
    }
    return filtered;
  })
  .subscribe(final => {
    this.list = final;
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this with some abstraction:

```
/* my.component.ts */

@Component(/* ... */)
export class MyComponent {
    /* ... */
    public mySub: Subscription = Observable.combineLatest(master$, filter1$, filter2$)
        .map((valueLists) => valueLists.filter((val) => val && val.length > 0))
        .map((valueLists) => ArrayUtils.intersection(...valueLists))
        .subscribe(final => this.list = final);
}


/* array.utils.ts */

export class ArrayUtils {
    public static intersection(...arrays: any[]): any[] {
        const result = [];
        /* Intersection logic... */
        return result;
    }
}
```

The intersection logic can also be taken from another source, such as the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#intersection) library.